# For iOS like android CoordinatorLayout

Tags: ios, swift

There is any lib or tutorial for iOS like android CoordinatorLayout with custom behavior. Actually I want is appbar scrolling view behaviour in iOS.

[image: The Header is move to navbar after scrolling]

[image]

Comment: Can put screen shot or gif here for understanding.

Comment: This is parallax view controller.

Comment: Thanks. ParallaxTableView is a part. I really want is header text move to nav bar after scrolling.

Comment: There is vertical scrolling segmentation control. check my answer with addition.

Answer (score 4):

This is call parallax view controller.

You can use this library - https://github.com/Vinodh-G/ParallaxTableViewHeader

It is really very good library.

It is able to integrate in swift.

**Swift code**

```
let headerView : ParallaxHeaderView = ParallaxHeaderView.parallaxHeaderViewWithImage(UIImage(named: ""), forSize: CGSizeMake(self.tableView.frame.size.height, headerHeight)) as! ParallaxHeaderView

self.tableView.tableHeaderView = headerView

func  scrollViewDidScroll(scrollView: UIScrollView) {

    let header: ParallaxHeaderView = self.tableView.tableHeaderView as! ParallaxHeaderView
    header.layoutHeaderViewForScrollViewOffset(scrollView.contentOffset)

    self.tblHealthData.tableHeaderView = header

}
```

**Addtion**

There is vertical scrolling segmentation control.

You can easily integrate with https://github.com/HighBay/PageMenu

Just understand 1,thing vertical scrolling segmentation no of controls have only 1 table view.

And you have to add parallax view controller on table view header.

All the best.